# Import Error : ImapLibrary robotframework-RIDE

Tags: python, jython, robotframework

I'm new to robotframwork. I'm able to work with Selenium2Library and other libraries. I tried to import the Imaplibrary after installation via pip it throws an error:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\prathod\Documents\automation\Registration.txt': Importing test library 'ImapLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named builtins
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ImapLibrary\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from builtins import str as ustr
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\jython2.7.0\Lib
  __classpath__
  __pyclasspath__/
  C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages
CLASSPATH:
  C:\jython2.7.0\jython.jar
  jars/Automaton-1.3.2-all-deps.jar
  \Users\prathod\AppData\Local\Abcd\app\Abcd-jfx.jar
  \Users\prathod\AppData\Local\Abcd\app\AbcdCore-jfx.jar
```

My environments are:
Classpath : C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext*.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib*.jar
PATH : %JAVA_HOME%\bin, C:\Python27\, C:\Python27\Scripts C:\jython2.7.0\bin

I am not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip install future --upgrade
```

then retry.